# Navbar content doesn't stay on same line when opening in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

This bootstrap navbar looks fine on desktop, but doesn't stay on the same line when viewed on mobile. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid"> <!--div1-->
  <div class="row"> <!--div3-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
      <div class="navbar-header"> <!--div2-->
        <a class="navbar-brand name-box" href="#">
          Text </a>
      </div> <!--div2-->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="name-box" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="name-box" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a class="name-box"href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div> <!--div3-->
</div> <!--div1-->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #2F4F2F;
}
.name-box {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: silver;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is responsive navbars. You need to use `collapse navbar-collapse` classes for small screen devices. You can find a good tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.htm under responsive navbar section

Comment: I added those classes and it ended up not displaying any of the <li> elements at all

Answer (score 0):

Problem in `.navbar-nav { }`

**Before**

[image]

**After** i added

```
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: All elements are still stacking and aren't on the same line

Comment: @st93 I don't understand you